# Linq Task - Group List elements and do action for grouped elements with condition

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have list somelist with objects `{bool someflag, int somevalue}`
I need to:

1. Filter list by someflag=true;
2. Group filtered list items by somevalue field;
3. Filter found groups that have less than 2 elements;
4. Change field somevalue for each element in filtered groups;

I did some trick to achieve this

```
somelist.FindAll(f => f.someflag)
            .GroupBy(g => g.somevalue).Where(g => g.Count() < 2).
            All(g => g.All(f => f.somevalue= -f.somevalue) == f.somevalue);
```

Is there more efficient and correct way?
Is it better to convert list and use ForEach?

Comment: That's a horrible way to modify the items in the query. Use a `foreach` block or if you must, create an equivalent extension.

Comment: Foreach requires type conversion, do you think it would be more optimal way?

Comment: Type conversion to what? You just want to loop over a set of items and perform some action to them... If anything, using unrelated linq operators to mimic that behavior is just a waste and confusing to read.

Comment: I mean no Foreach metod for IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I refactor this a little bit.

```
var valuesToChange = new HashSet<int>();
somelist.Where(item => item.someflag).ForEach(item => valuesToChange.Add(item.somevalue));
somelist.Where(item => valuesToChange.Contains(item.somevalue)).ForEach(item => item.somevalue = -item.somevalue);
```

HashSet should improve your performance, cause it cannot store the duplicated elements and the elements are not ordered. The rest of the code should be self-explanatory. If you care a lot about the performance I recommend using BenchmarkDotNet for performance results.

Basically, this code should improve the performance a little, depending on the list size.

Comment: Hashset imposible because there is no unique records.